TypeORM skips entity properties when it parses DB raw data
I've got a nest.js project with mongodb and typeorm.
There is a method that loads all records from a mongo document (there are <10 records). I do it, roughly, like this:
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  public constructor(
    @InjectRepository(MyEntity)
    private readonly myEntity: Repository<MyEntity>
  ) {}

  public loadAllRecords() {
    return this.myEntity.find();
  }
}

Simplified entity:
@Entity({ name: 'my_entity' })
export class MyEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn({
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 50,
    name: '_id',
  })
  @ObjectIdColumn({
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 50,
    name: '_id',
  })
  public alias: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 100,
    unique: true,
    nullable: false,
    name: 'default_name',
  })
  public defaultName: string;
}

In other places similar code works perfectly. In this particular place typeorm loads correct raw data (I've logged and checked it), but then it puts only the alias in the created entity instance. Pay attention, it doesn't set a default_name property, it doesn't set any properties, aside from the alias at all. So, the metadata works, since _id is correctly parsed into alias, the data extraction works, there must be something wrong with the transformation. Metadata of the other columns, other than alias, seems fine, but maybe you'd tell me which exact properties to check.
There are no reported bugs like this one (at least I haven't been able to find them). Most likely, nobody can tell me what is wrong exactly, so the question I ask is this: which JS files from the typeorm in the node_modules folder can I use to add console.logs to see how the raw DB data is handled to create entity instances? So I would be able to see why the rest of the properties are skipped.
